# CSS Flipping Cube

Tags: css, animation, rotation, css-transitions, transition

I made some expriment with CSS3. I wanted to build a Flipping Cube with only 2 DIV.Like this:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-flipping-cube 
(I dont like this solution because the div must always be centered)
So I have tried to find my own solution.
My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="face face1">Click here !</div>
  <div class="face face2"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS file looks like this:

```
.outer { margin-left:52px; position:relative; width:400px; perspective:500px; }
.face { width:100%; height:50px; padding:0 10px; background-color:#E5E5E5; position:absolute; }
.face.face1 { height:50px; background-color:#E5E5E5; transform:rotateX(0deg); transform-origin:0 0 0; z-index:1; top:0; }
.face.face2 { height:50px; background-color:#007CC1; transform:rotateX(-90deg); transform-origin:0 50px 0; z-index:3; top:0; }
.face.face1.start { transform:rotateX(90deg); transition:transform 1s ease-out; }
.face.face2.start { transform:rotateX(0deg); transition:transform 1s ease-out; }
```

When I click on the `face1` then javascript adds the class start to the divs for are the animation.

```
$(function(){
    $('.outer').on('click', function(){
        $('.face1').addClass('start');
        $('.face2').addClass('start');
    });
});
```

My solution looks currently not good. Do you have any tips or idea for me. You can see the whole code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dAXRX/3/

(I didn't use the `-webkit` prefix. It currently only works with Firefox)

Comment: What don't you like about your solution? Too slow? Also, I can't readily see what you mean about that other solution being centered.

Comment: that doesn't look like a qube

Comment: I think the problem is that the sides of the blue rectangle need to start skewed and and transform as it rotates to keep its shape. You might start by looking at the trapezium and parallelogram at http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/